# Is there a GUI, portable, small tool for Windows that asks to select a folder or a file and then writes it to stdout?

Tags: windows, batch, zenity

At work we constantly write CMD batch scripts that will take one, two, or three folders as parameters.

As sometimes the end users would be interested in using those scripts, and as is it long, boring, error-prone and fastidious to type in cmd a command-line with three folder paths as arguments I would like to be able to do like this on Linux:

```
my_destination_folder="$(zenity --folder-selector --title "choose your folder")"
```

with some tool like:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G IN (`XXX.exe`) do SET my_destination_folder=%%G
```

Do you know any simple tool that can be my `XXX.exe`?

Possibly a standalone, minimalistic tool...

Thank you

Comment: You can drag and drop files/folders onto a batch script icon to execute the script with those items as parameters.  No typing required.

Comment: Yes I know. It even insert appropriate quotes, but still you must not forget to type spaces between arguments

Comment: No.  Try this, make a batch file on your desktop that contains `echo %1 echo %2 etc..` then select and drag a few folders onto it's icon on the desktop.

Comment: I mean that the order is important. Thus I don't drop more than one folder at the same time

Comment: I would think that an `AutoIt` program could be made for this, where a dialogue box would instruct the user to click on the three required folders in turn.

Comment: @paradroid: Your comment led me to write a solution involving compiling an 2-line AutoIt script of my own. Please, put your comment as a new answer to score!

Comment: @Benoit: Done.  Glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that an [**AutoIt**](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) program could be made for this, where a dialogue box would instruct the user to click on the three required folders in turn.

Answer (score 2):

Seemed like an interesting idea so I made another one for you :)

Here is your XXX.exe: [**Link**](http://www.4shared.com/file/q849mQKy/XXX.html)

Source code is included.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This one will be great for people having the .NET frameword installed. Unfortunately some of our users won't. Still, +1 for it.

Comment: To those wishing to re-use this code, it requires a custom FolderOpenDialog class from the .NET zip library: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I found [Wizard Apprentice](http://wizapp.sourceforge.net). Still, it does not directly open a file selection dialog, you have to click a browse button.